# Moving to s3 storage with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get ready to move a node.js application I've been working on into a production environment (I'm using Heroku). Users add images to the site via url. Right now they are just saved on the server- I'd like to move the storage to s3 but am having some difficulties.

The idea is to save the image to disk first and then upload it, but I'm struggling to find a way to be notified when the file has finished writing to the disk. It seems like it doesn't use the typical node callback style.

Here is the code as it is now. I'm using [the request node module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) which may be complicating things rather than simplifying them:

```
    requestModule(request.payload.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./public/img/submittedContent/" + name));

                // what do I do here?

                fs.readFile("./public/img/submittedContent/" + name, function(err, data){
                if (err) { console.warn(err); }
                else {
                    s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: "submitted_images",
                        Key: name,
                        Body: data
                     }).done(function(s3response){
                        console.log("success!");
                        reply({message:'success'});
                    }).fail(function(s3response){
                        console.log("failure");
                        reply({message:'failure'});
                    });
                }
            });
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there are a couple of s3 libraries on NPM which it might be worth checking out, including [s3](https://www.npmjs.org/package/s3), [streaming-s3](https://www.npmjs.org/package/streaming-s3) and [s3-upload-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/s3-upload-stream). You could also use the [official Amazon SDK](https://www.npmjs.org/package/aws-sdk) directly. Here are [some S3 examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service__Amazon_S3_)

Comment: Right now I actually am using the official SDK, the s3.putObject call. The issue is getting the reference to the data for the body parameter- I'm not sure how to make the readFile call after it has finished writing to disk. I'll look into the other s3 libraries you suggest though. Thanks!

Comment: You know, my apologies for not fully reading your question, when I saw you mentioning using the `request` module I (reflexively and wrongly) presumed you were likely trying to simply post to S3 via `request` rather than appreciating you were using it just for the fetching. Although since you're getting a stream already, I wonder if you could use one of the s3 streaming libs - or minimally look at how they implement the streaming upload. So is your core question above how you are 'notified' when the write stream has finished?

Comment: Yes- I probably should have made that more clear. It looks like I could have some luck with the libraries you mentioned. I'll look at them more closely tomorrow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening for the `finish` event on the writable stream:

```
requestModule(request.payload.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./public/img/submittedContent/" + name)).on('finish', function(){
    // do stuff with saved file
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried listening for an 'end' event. How did you know to listen for finish? [The docs only mention open, change, and error.](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

Comment: Its not part of the FS API. Its from the Steam API which FS implements. http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're modifying the image, you shouldn't upload to Heroku - but rather directly to S3.

See [Direct to S3 File Uploads in Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node)

Comment: I'll be making thumbnails of all added images.